# How to get the below result from this table?

Tags: sql, aggregation

TeamDetails

```
Team1       Team2       Winner      
India       Pakistan    India       
India       Srilanka    India       
Srilanka    India       India       
Pakistan    Srilanka    Srilanka        
Pakistan    England     Pakistan        
Srilanka    England     Srilanka
```

Write a query to get the following result

```
Team    No.of Matches Played    No.of Matches Won   No.of Matches Lost  
India       3                          3                  0   
Pakistan    3                          1                  2   
Srilanka    4                          2                  2   
England     2                          0                  2
```

Comment: Can you also show us any attempts you have made to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to get result in sql server.. then please remove oracle tag

Comment: Homework... You'll not learn much if we do it for you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select team1 as team,SUM(totalplay) as totalplay,SUM(won) as won,SUM(lost) as lost 
  from 
 (select  team1,count(*) as totalplay,
  sum(case when winner = team1 then 1 else 0 end) as won,
  sum(case when winner != team1 then 1 else 0 end) as Lost from @t1
  group by team1
     union all
 select  team2,count(*) as totalplay,
   sum(case when winner = team2 then 1 else 0 end) as won,
   sum(case when winner != team2 then 1 else 0 end) as Lost from @t1
  group by team2) as t
group by team1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Team, SUM(matches_played) as matches_played, SUM(matches_won) as matches_won, SUM(matches_lost) as matches_lost FROM (
 SELECT a.Team1 as Team,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TeamDetails where a.Team1 IN (TeamDetails.Team1, TeamDetails.Team2)) as matches_played,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TeamDetails where a.Team1 = TeamDetails.Winner) as matches_won,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TeamDetails where a.Team1 IN (TeamDetails.Team1, TeamDetails.Team2) AND a.Team1 <> TeamDetails.Winner) as matches_lost
 FROM TeamDetails a
 GROUP BY Team1
 UNION
 SELECT a.Team2,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TeamDetails where a.Team2 IN (TeamDetails.Team1, TeamDetails.Team2)) as matches_played,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TeamDetails where a.Team2 = TeamDetails.Winner) as matches_won,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TeamDetails where a.Team2 IN (TeamDetails.Team1, TeamDetails.Team2) AND a.Team2 <> TeamDetails.Winner) as matches_lost
 FROM TeamDetails a
 GROUP BY Team2 ) x
 GROUP BY Team
```

Please try this.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to achieve your expected output:

```
WITH all_team AS
(
    SELECT team1 AS team 
    FROM table_name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT team2 
    FROM table_name
),
team_count AS
(
    SELECT team,
        COUNT(*) AS count_play
    FROM all_team
    GROUP BY team
),
win_count AS
(
    SELECT winner AS team,
        COUNT(*) AS count_win
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY winner
),
lose_count AS
(
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN winner = team1
            THEN team2
            ELSE team1
        END AS team,
        COUNT(*) AS count_lose
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY
        CASE WHEN winner = team1
            THEN team2
            ELSE team1
        END
)
SELECT tc.team,
    tc.count_play AS "No.of Matches Played",
    COALESCE(wc.count_win, 0) AS "No.of Matches Won",    --NVL(wc.count_win, 0)
    COALESCE(lc.count_lose, 0) AS "No.of Matches Lost"
FROM team_count tc
LEFT JOIN win_count wc
ON tc.team = wc.team
LEFT JOIN lose_count lc
ON tc.team = lc.team;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want according to order of No. of matches lost then try below code

```
SELECT a.Team1,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TeamDetails where a.Team1 IN (TeamDetails.Team1, TeamDetails.Team2)) as matches_played,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TeamDetails where a.Team1 = TeamDetails.Winner) as matches_won,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TeamDetails where a.Team1 IN (TeamDetails.Team1, TeamDetails.Team2) AND a.Team1 <> TeamDetails.Winner) as matches_lost
 FROM TeamDetails a
 GROUP BY Team1
 UNION
 SELECT a.Team2,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TeamDetails where a.Team2 IN (TeamDetails.Team1, TeamDetails.Team2)) as matches_played,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TeamDetails where a.Team2 = TeamDetails.Winner) as matches_won,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TeamDetails where a.Team2 IN (TeamDetails.Team1, TeamDetails.Team2) AND a.Team2 <> TeamDetails.Winner) as matches_lost
 FROM TeamDetails a
 GROUP BY Team2
 ORDER BY matches_lost,matches_won
```